# Homebrew installs nvm but nvm can't be found afterwards?

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-yosemite, oh-my-zsh, nvm

I'm using `homebrew` and `oh-my-zsh` on a fresh OSX 10.10.1 install. I got `nvm` via `homebrew` and then attempted to run it but says - *zsh: command not found: nvm*

Any idea what the problem is? I was able to install and use git just fine...

[image]

[image]

---

**UPDATED 9/20/2019**

As stated by more recent answers from [DarkPurple141](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7650430/darkpurple141) and [Elise van Looij](https://stackoverflow.com/users/126126/elise-van-looij). `nvm` doesn't appear to be compatible with `homebrew`. This is also stated in the official nvm-sh repo located [here](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installation-and-update).

> Homebrew installation is not supported. If you have issues with
> homebrew-installed nvm, please brew uninstall it, and install it using
> the instructions below, before filing an issue.
>
> Note: If you're using zsh you can easily install nvm as a zsh plugin.
> Install zsh-nvm and run nvm upgrade to upgrade.

The following steps should help:

1. $ `brew uninstall nvm`
2. $ `brew cleanup` (just for good measure)
3. $ `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash`
4. Check that nvm was installed correctly by running $ `command -v nvm`.

   4.a If the response is anything other than $ `nvm`, add the following two lines to the ~/.bash-profile file:
   `export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm`
   `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`

   4.b Restart your computer (you can try closing Terminal and restarting it first)

   4.c $ `command -v nvm should now return` nvm`
5. Now update Node.js with $ `nvm install --lts`
6. Update npm: $ `nvm install-latest-npm`
7. $ `npm install --global mocha`. Finally, success! Well, for me and I hope for you too.

Comment: Does it persist if you restart Terminal?

Comment: Try typing rehash  or opening a new shell. Sometimes zsh doesn't pick up additions.

Comment: I've closed the shell, rebooted system and nothing. Did rehash and no luck.

Comment: How about brew link nvm  does that do anything ?

Comment: Warning: Already linked: /usr/local/Cellar/nvm/0.20.0
To relink: brew unlink nvm && brew link nvm

Comment: nano .bash_profile is your friend for 4.a. Thanks Dayan!

Comment: echo 'export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"' >> ~/.zshrc
echo '[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh"' >> ~/.zshrc

Note: If you're using Bash instead of Zsh, replace ~/.zshrc with ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Did you follow the instructions listed in the caveats?

```
[~] brew info nvm
nvm: stable 0.20.0, HEAD
https://github.com/creationix/nvm
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/nvm.rb
==> Caveats
Add the following to $HOME/.bashrc, $HOME/.zshrc, or your shell's
equivalent configuration file:

  source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh

Node installs will be lost upon upgrading nvm. Add the following above
the source line to move install location and prevent this:

  export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
```

Without the extra config it doesn't look like it will find NVM by default..

Comment: Thank you for the heads up Doon, i was not aware of `brew info`, still new to `homebrew` :) Its working good now after following those steps.

Comment: They should be shown after the install completes as well. But if you are not looking for them they can be missed.

Comment: I had to add this to by `~/.bash_profile` to get it working :/

Comment: hmm. I don't use bash(prefer zsh), but it looks like OSX terminal.app (I don't use terminal either, prefer Iterm2), opens each shell as a login shell so yes .bash_profile would be correct in that case.. also the info has changed. so you should refer to the latest version..

Comment: Thanks! I was missing this line 
  `source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh`. Added it to my .zshrh

Comment: A little more is needed. Don't forget to apply the changes by running the script! I noted this in https://stackoverflow.com/a/37613432/339803

Comment: this slows down terminal startup

Answer (score 66):

There are TWO things you need to do. Follow the caveats shown after installing nvm via brew, and THEN you need to **activate/reload the .bash_profile/.zshrc changes.**

1. Run `brew install nvm`
2. Follow caveats shown in console, mine were as follows, yours MAY be different!:

> Add the following to `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.zshrc` or your desired shell configuration file:
>
> ```
> export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
> . "$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh"
> ```

3. Run `. ~/.bash_profile` to apply the changes you made to your .bash_profile file (Adjust as required for `.zshrc` and similar)

Comment: This is useful for Bash users, but the OP is on zsh. I guess the same applies to `.zshrc` with the necessary modifications.

Comment: Thanks. (if you're on zsh, just type command, `bash` and then apply the steps)

Comment: Years later I see the above comment made, and notice I am since then now also using zsh instead of bash lol. Also adjusted my answer to also include zsh, as per other comment.

Answer (score 22):

I've spent a couple of hours going round and round on this issue, but I've come to the conclusion that DarkPurple141 is right: nvm just isn't compatible with Homebrew, as they state on their Github [nvm-sh/nvm Node Version Manager](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installation-and-update). Homebrew will install nvm and everything looks fine, until one tries to get npm to install a module, Mocha in my case. That threw me right back to the dreaded error:

> ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'

NOTE: On step 3, make sure to replace version with correct release.

The solution, on MacOS 10.14 Mojave, was:

1. $ `brew uninstall nvm`
2. $ `brew cleanup` (just for good measure)
3. $ `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.0/install.sh | bash`
4. Check that nvm was installed correctly by running $ `command -v nvm`.

   4.a If the response is anything other than $ `nvm`, add the following two lines to the ~/.bash-profile file:
       `export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm`
       `source ~/.nvm/nvm.sh`
   4.b Restart your computer (you can try closing Terminal and restarting it first)
   4.c $ `command -v nvm should now return`nvm`
5. Now update Node.js with $ `nvm install --lts`
6. Update npm: $ `nvm install-latest-npm`
7. $ `npm install --global mocha`. Finally, success! Well, for me and I hope for you too.

Comment: For the people who are using zshrc instead of bash use the following command in the step number 4.a:
`nano ~/.zshrc`

Now you add the two commands, restart the terminal and you're good to go :)

Comment: Just to add, at step 4 one need to add complete info to .bash_profile returned from step 3. Mine was like :
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/nvm.sh"  # This loads nvm
  [ -s "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm" ] && \. "/opt/homebrew/opt/nvm/etc/bash_completion.d/nvm"  # This loads nvm bash_completion 
and then run . ~/.bash_profile to keep the terminal ready to use it.

Comment: step 4 was extremely helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

To install nvm, `brew install nvm`

To run nvm after installation or just once, `$(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh`

To run nvm everytime `zsh` opens

1. `nano ~/.zshrc`
2. Add this line `source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh`

Answer (score 8):

While the accepted answer does technically work, it's worth noting that Homebrew installation is not officially supported by the `nvm` package. The recommended way to avoid issues like those raised above is to apply either of the below methods of installation.

```sh
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash

# or wget:
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.34.0/install.sh | bash
```

source: https://github.com/creationix/nvm

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this, like many here, but all the suggested options only worked until I restarted the terminal.
Here's an option that fixed it

Create NVM’s working directory.

```
mkdir ~/.nvm
```

Edit your shell config file to add the path to the NVM home directory. The shell config file would be ~/.bash_profile if you are using Bash, or ~./zshrc if you are using Zsh, the default shell for MacOS Catalina and later versions.

```
# open config file
nano ~/.zshrc
```

Add the following to the config file.

```
# add the nvm path
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
# load the nvm script every time you open the terminal
source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh
```

Close your nano editor and verify the path to the home directory with the commands below.

```
source ~/.zshrc                   # reload config file
echo $NVM_DIR                     # echo path
nvm --version                     # check nvm version
```

Comment: I think installing oh-my-zsh seems to have overwritten this even when I had done it already. Thank you for writing this out so I could restore my .zshrc :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason you would need to reload your bash profiles or any other bash files might be because the command nvm may not be a program but a function that is defined and can only be used if the corresponding bash file is sourced.

On a system that I checked

```
which nvm
```

does not work but

```
nvm list
```

does. This means that you can use the word "nvm" to invoke something. That something isn't a program. In the current case, it is a function which can be verified by

```
typeset -F | grep -P ' nvm$'
```

which outputs

```
declare -F nvm
```

which means nvm is a function, whose body can be inspected by doing

```
type -F nvm
```

Comment: Nice.. But, how is this an answer?

Comment: Thanks for the update Dayan - edited the answer - the reason why I couldn't find it because I was relying on it being a program but it was defined as a function. Wanted to highlight that.

Comment: To check whether nvm has been installed properly use 'command -v nvm' in the Terminal. The response should be 'nvm'. If it's not, follow the instructions on https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm#installation-and-update.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility if `brew` was used is that the `nvm` may be unlinked, especially if it was installed by another MAC OS user.

In this case, execute:

```
brew link nvm
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to add that nvm's location on github changed and the version bumped.
The curl command now should be:

```
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.35.0/install.sh | bash
```

Answer (score 1):

> Instructions from
> [lukechilds/zsh-nvm#as-an-oh-my-zsh-custom-plugin](https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm)

If you are using macos + zsh + oh-my-zsh:

1. Clone zsh-nvm into your custom plugins repo

   ```
   git clone https://github.com/lukechilds/zsh-nvm ~/.oh-my-zsh/custom/plugins/zsh-nvm
   ```
2. Then load nvm as a plugin in your .zshrc file

   ```
   plugins+=(zsh-nvm)
   ```

   Keep in mind that plugins need to be added before oh-my-zsh.sh is sourced.

   f.e.

   ```
   $ nano ~/.zshrc

   // edit .zshrc contents
   ...
   # Which plugins would you like to load?
   # Standard plugins can be found in $ZSH/plugins/
   # Custom plugins may be added to $ZSH_CUSTOM/plugins/
   # Example format: plugins=(rails git textmate ruby lighthouse)
   # Add wisely, as too many plugins slow down shell startup.
   # docs: f.e. https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/tree/master/plugins/kubectl

   plugins=(zsh-nvm)

   source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
   ...
   ```
3. Finally reload the configuration `$ source ~/.zshrc`

Comment: This was exactly what I had been looking for it worked so well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you happen to be using [fish shell](https://fishshell.com/), consider https://github.com/jorgebucaran/nvm.fish