# nvm: command not found after running nvm install 6.3.0

Tags: bash

I am a beginner programmer having trouble installing node 6.3.0.

I successfully ran the command:

```
brew install nvm
```

but i get the error listed "nvm command not found" when I try to run

```
nvm install 6.3.0
```

From google it seems like I likely have an issue with my .bash_profile but nothing I've found works.  Right now my .bash profile reads like

```
this:export RBENV_ROOT=/usr/local/var/rbenv
rbenv > /dev/null; eval "$(rbenv init -)"
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/latest/bin
```

I know there needs to be something added for Node but I can't figure out what, also once I do figure out how to install 6.3.0, how do I make it my default version?

Thanks!

Comment: check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16904658/node-version-manager-install-nvm-command-not-found

Comment: already did...I think my issue is different since I installed it with homebrew

Comment: ok, but just to be sure, you've already tried including `[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh` right?

Comment: yeah, I've tried that and it does nothing :(

Answer (score 2):

For Mac OS X users I would like to provide some steps which I followed and helped me with the installation of Node Version Manager a.k.a. nvm.

**Installing & using nvm on Mac OS X**

- Install homebrew from [here](https://brew.sh/).
- Using homebrew install nvm

  `brew update
  brew install nvm`
- Create `.nvm` directory at `~/.nvm` location.

  `mkdir ~/.nvm`
- Now if you don't have `.bash_profile` file setup for OS X terminal then please create a `.bash_profile` at the root level:

  `nano ~/.bash_profile`
- Paste below code in the `.bash_profile` and press `CTRL + O` and press enter to save `.bash_profile` file. Press `CTRL + X` to exit from editor:

  `export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
   source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh`
- Now either quite (`CMD + Q`) the terminal or run below command to load `.bash_profile` settings:

  `source ~/.bash_profile`
- Now run `nvm ls` command to get the list of all installed nodejs versions.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the following instructions:

```
[~] brew info nvm
nvm: stable 0.20.0, HEAD
https://github.com/creationix/nvm
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/nvm.rb
==> Caveats
Add the following to $HOME/.bashrc, $HOME/.zshrc, or your shell's
equivalent configuration file:

  source $(brew --prefix nvm)/nvm.sh

Node installs will be lost upon upgrading nvm. Add the following above
the source line to move install location and prevent this:

  export NVM_DIR=~/.nvm
```

this was taken from: [Homebrew installs nvm but nvm can't be found afterwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651892/homebrew-installs-nvm-but-nvm-cant-be-found-afterwards)