# Issues installing nvm on Mac from command line

Tags: react-native

I've tried setting up React Native/Visual Studio Code, and when trying to run a basic "Hello World" app using the command line, I run into an issue when running `react-native run-ios`.

When I do that, I get this message:

[image]

So I try the suggestion of running `nvm install 8.3 --reinstall-packages-from=node`, and I get the error:

`nvm: command not found`

My next step was following [this solution from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41203466/nvm-command-not-found-after-running-nvm-install-6-3-0). I went through the steps but when it came time to `Create .nvm directory at ~/.nvm location` using `mkdir ~/.nvm`, I realized that I was currently within the project file (the Hello World project I was trying to run). I ran the `mkdir ~/.nvm` and the nvm folder appeared, but since I thought it was the wrong place for it, I dragged the folder to the trash.

Now upon trying to start over from step one, installing nvm from home-brew, I get another few errors:

[image]

My question is, was that indeed the wrong place to create the .nvm directory? Did I screw up by dragging that folder to the trash? How do I undo whatever I messed up and get nvm working so I can run my react native app?

Thanks a lot for any help!

EDIT: If I rerun the home-brew command, I get the error

`Error: nvm 0.33.11 is already installed`

So I tried upgrading with `brew upgrade nvm`, and that seemed to go well but now when I retry my initial command of `nvm install 8.3 --reinstall-packages-from=node`, I get:

`-bash: nvm: command not found`

Comment: try installing it via homebrew again...

Comment: @rogerdpack See my edit

Comment: When you install nvm via homebrew it spits out some instructions regarding modifying ".bash_profile" to "load nvm"

Comment: Yes, it tells me to create an NVM directory with `mkdir ~/.nvm`, which is where my issues started - I'm not sure where to make this directory, since running `mkdir ~/.nvm` in terminal created the folder in whatever directory I'm in (which right now is the Hello World project). Do I just make the directory there?

Comment: If it's your home dir then yeah that's right