# Missing write access in mac to /usr/local/lib/node_modules

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-cli, node-modules

I am trying to install angular cli but it's show me Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules 
so, how can I fix it in my mac i try it may time but, not getting exact answer

```
 npm WARN checkPermissions Missing write access to /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall access
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules']
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, access \'/usr/local/lib/node_modules\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'access',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules' }
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```

Comment: Have you tried:
```sudo npm install```?

Comment: yes, i try with that

Comment: Can you create any file or folder at this path ```/usr/local/lib/node_modules``` manually? Either usually or through sudo.

Comment: No, its auto created while installing node js

Comment: Can you please check is node_modules dir is there on above path ?

Comment: @SergeyKirienko finally I found the solution thanks to trying to help me

Comment: @KundanKumarMourya how do you fixed it?

Comment: @ShaithyaKannan i just uninstall node js and npm  and reinstall its, after that issue is fix.

Comment: Adding sudo worked for me

Comment: I've wrestled with a similar issue with npm (trying to install Mocha). In another answer, I learned that the solution lay in using an nvm (NodeJS Version Manager). That brought its own problems, but I now have everything working without messing with the permissions. I've broken the whole procedure down in 7 steps in my answer to [Homebrew installs nvm but nvm can't be found afterwards?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27651892/homebrew-installs-nvm-but-nvm-cant-be-found-afterwards/57557509#57557509)

Answer (score 188):

Run these commands in a terminal window:

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/lib/node_modules
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
```

Comment: I tried this code but when I run the second command then I am getting chown: /usr/lib/node_modules: No such file or directory

Comment: The second command might not work but its okay. First and third one is enough. At least worked for me.

Comment: 'sudo chown -R $USER /usr/lib/node_modules' - this command dont really needed , since local modules installed into /usr/local/lib/node_modules path

Comment: Can someone confirm my understanding please ? sudo: "do this with admin powers" // chown: "update who owns this file/directory as a user/group" // -R : "this dir and all its directories & files" // $USER : a global variable that contains the user actually logged ? // path.
Thanks!

Comment: @Dimitri - exactly correct ($USER is an environment variable set to the logged-in user's name)

Comment: This solves my first issue on fresh install of node.js in mac and also it's terminal usage   in VS Code

Comment: This answer doesn't work when I run npm uninstall -g package

Comment: I had to run `sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin/` on my mac M1 to make it work

Answer (score 67):

I had this issue, I could fixed it by calling sudo on every global install. I wasn't ok with that.

I followed the [n package installation](https://github.com/tj/n) advices to be able to install npm packages without sudo.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib /usr/local/include /usr/local/share
```

Answer of @jeduard didn't work for me.

Comment: Optional: on another machine I had the same issue and I forgot about this solution. So I searched and found another one from npm themselves: https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally .
Turns out it wasn't working so easily (needed to 'source ~/.profile' time to time).
I did what I've answered here and everything works like a charm. I'm just sharing another way of handling this issue.

Comment: Answer of @jeduard didn't work for me either. I'm on Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 34):

Best way to solve your `npm install -g` issues:

https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

This way, you will never need to use `SUDO` or `change permissions`.

**Quoting**:

1. Back up your computer.
2. On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

   ```
   mkdir ~/.npm-global
   ```
3. Configure npm to use the new directory path:

   ```
   npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
   ```
4. In your preferred text editor, open or create a  `~/.profile`  file and add this line:

   ```
   export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
   ```
5. On the command line, update your system variables:

   ```
   source ~/.profile
   ```

Comment: Same this worked for me.

I use Iterm and ZSH so I had to do the following as well so that it will work every time I open the terminal and don't have to run source ~/.profile each time
After Creating the ~/.profile I added `source ~/.profile` to my .zshrc file

Comment: I agree with the source of the problem ! Never use sudo with NPM (https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-5711d2726aa3) 

As solution, I prefer to use nvm that will create the correct npm folders for u. (and nvm is an important tool to install if you are working on different projects)

Answer (score 10):

Appending `sudo` before the `npm install` saved my day:

```
sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Once you provide your system password, installation should finish smoothly:

[image: Attaching Screenshot]

Comment: That's a really BAD idea ! You should never use sudo with npm ! 
https://medium.com/@ExplosionPills/dont-use-sudo-with-npm-5711d2726aa3

The best and easiest solution is to use nvm that will create you node_modules folder with the correct access-rights in a correct folder (and that solution is provided by the OFFICIAL npm documentation !) https://docs.npmjs.com/resolving-eacces-permissions-errors-when-installing-packages-globally

Answer (score 4):

Same problem. I reinstalled the latest version of node via https://nodejs.org/en/download/ instead of using terminal. This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue when trying to install React -- issues with permissions being denied.

This is where SUDO can come in handy, it allows a permitted user to execute a command as the superuser or another user. Think of like "Run as Administrator" on Windows. If you type in the following command, it should allow you to access all of the needed folders with the proper elevated access.

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib /usr/local/include /usr/local/share
```

This is also denoted in [Dimitri's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12603016/dimitri) answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60791736/3803726

Answer (score 1):

For macOS try to run -

```
sudo chown -R $USER ~/.npm
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/lib/node_modules
sudo chown -R $USER /usr/local/bin/
```

If this still doesn't work you might need to add sudo to the npm install command.

Answer (score 0):

If you're *really* blocked on installing NPM modules globally (e.g. on some corporate laptop), you could just install them all in a single local folder somewhere and then add the path to node_modules/.bin/ to your PATH environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
type this cmd in terminal

```
sudo nautilus
```

after that, it opens another file manager that has root access

[image]

after that type

```
    sudo apt install nodejs 
    sudo apt install npm 
    sudo npm install -g npm@latest
    sudo npm install -g @angular/cli
    ng --version
```

Comment: The original question seems to be mac-related, while this answer seems to refer to a Debian based Linux system. This migh be helpful for others but should be mentioned explicitly.